# How to check if auto app updates is enabled in play store programatically?

Tags: android, google-play-services, playback, auto-update

How to check if auto app updates is enabled in play store programatically in android?

Also, what is the intent to navigate user to this screen to disable it?

[Play Store App Updates Settings Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jdub.png)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNn5V.jpg)

Please help

Comment: I don't think that you can access Google Play settings from your app

Comment: because surelock app already does it. [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock)